# Running docker build within a shell script

Tags: bash, docker, sh, dockerfile

I'm trying to set up a simple shell script that will do something along the following lines. Let's call it `docker_maker.sh`:

```
do stuff
docker build -t my-registry.com/my_image:latest .
docker push my-registry.com/my_image:latest
do more stuff
```

But when I call the script:

```
cd /where/my/dockerfile/is
sh docker_maker.sh
```

I get the following error:

```
unable to prepare context: path ".\r" not found
```

It seems that what is happening is that the docker build command is including the `.\r` linebreak characters as part of the build call. Is there a way that I could avoid this from happening?

Comment: This is strange. Can you pass the file via dos2unix and see if the issue persists? Looks like `docker build ... .` picks up a unreadable character `\r` somewhere. Or can you try placing the dot inside a `"` and a space after it, like `...:latest "."   `?

Comment: Yep, that was the problem. The file was created in Windows and deployed to a Linux instance. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39527571/are-shell-scripts-sensitive-to-encoding-and-line-endings (of which, now that I know the answer, my question is obviously a duplicate) explains it pretty well. Thanks